# create drag and drop event c++

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, visual-c++, c++builder

How to send drag and drop files to other program from my program in background with c++ WIN API. 
My program must do that programatically without user action, without visible effects, smooth in background. 
I'm not very familiar with drag and drop techniques, and so far I understood that I need to use OLE drag and drop operation.

Comment: What do you mean "programmatically simulate drag and drop for other program"? Your program is not going to be able to force a *different* program to begin a drag-and-drop operation. Do you just mean that you want your program to be able to receive dropped items?

Comment: I mean: simulate drag and drop for other program, I want to create a drag and drop object and send it to other program which is able to receive dropped items.

Comment: @CodyGray did you checked next 2 links: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742859.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dragdrop.dodragdrop.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-1

Comment: Okay, that's not a simulation. That's just registering your application as a drop source, accomplished by implementing the `IDropSource` interface. But now I'm confused. The links you posted are about the .NET Framework, not the Windows API. Which one are you looking for?

Comment: maybe you post a sample code and I will test

Comment: @CodyGray I think it is something very related to OLE programming. Actually I will use win api code in C++ Builder

Comment: How do you know what the target app is? Do you have a window handle for it?

Comment: @Pete I can find window handle using WINAPI FindWindow function

Comment: Is your background application running as a service ? It will make matters much worse because you will have to cross both session and process boundaries.

Comment: Windows does not help background programs give the user a third invisible hand. I like [Raymond Chen general reasoning about this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/06/07/426294.aspx). I don't know if it will be possible, but you will swimming upstream for sure.

Comment: @ixe013 it is not running as service

Comment: I see you've bountied this, but it's still not clear to me exactly what you're trying to achieve. What goes wrong with the sample code you posted? And what is `TDropSource`? `IDropSource` is an interface and has an `I` prefix. Yours begins with a `T`, and is instantiated with `new`. Can't do that with an interface.

Answer (score 2):

You may check this code link

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/12/06/275659.aspx

Then to use this code you may use a COM ActiveX in visual studio as follows

// declare a single instance of the DropTarget class

```
CDropSource codrop;

BOOL CALLBACK 
DlgProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
   switch (message)
      { 
      case WM_INITDIALOG:
     // bind the drop target to the dialog
     codrop.SetHwnd(hwnd);
     RegisterDragDrop(hwnd, &codrop);
     return TRUE;
      case WM_COMMAND:
     if (LOWORD(wParam) == IDCANCEL)
        EndDialog(hwnd, IDCANCEL);
     return TRUE;
     case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
       OnLButtonDown(hwnd, false,
               LOWORD(lParam), HIWORD(lParam), 0);
      break;
      case WM_DESTROY:
     // unbind the drop target from the dialog
     RevokeDragDrop(hwnd);
     return FALSE;
      }

   return FALSE;
}
```

// the standard WinMain for an Applet

```
int WINAPI 
WinMain(HINSTANCE hinstance, HINSTANCE, LPSTR, int)
{
   OleInitialize(0);
   DialogBox(hinstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_DIALOG1), 0, DlgProc);
   OleUninitialize();
   return 0;
}
```

of course I didn't test the code it might need a lot of tweaking to work, but you get the idea

I guess you can use this shell API to implment wuty

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762151(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: If you read the original question again, you will find that the OP was asking how to simulate a drop onto another application's window. This is not the same as what you posted here.

Comment: the drag and drop are implemented by the OS, I asked him : " First of all what I understood is that your application which should have a COM interface, it can be a drop source or a drop target or can support both, if you are a drop source then if some one drag your window to his window you need to use this API to determine if he is a valid target and send the data out to him and then the drag and drop can be performed Are u doing so ? wut I understand from your code is that your are trying to use the function but I don't know where"

Comment: however if he wants to do it he will need to have a third application to do that, the application can control the mouse movement from the first one to the second one while both apps support the COM interface or he might use the WM_DROPFILES message but I am not sure it will work